# How do the Flames work?

Tags: small-world-underground

I'm a little unclear on the wording of the Flames. What does "Empty" mean? Does it ignore mountains? Shields? I'm fairly certain it ignores troops.

Side question (maybe this should be a separate question?!) can Flames travel through the Great Brass Pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty does not mean "needs 2 critters to conquer" it means without monster or race tokens.

From the rules, bottom of page 9

> A Region is deemed non-empty if, and only if, it contains at
>   least one Monster or Race token (Active or In Decline). A Region
>   that contains a Black Mountain marker, a Popular Place or a
>   Righteous Relic but no Monster or enemy Race token is
>   considered empty.

The Great Brass Pipe considers spaces adjacent for the purposes of the owning race, so Flames should be continuous through it.  This is confirmed in the [FAQ](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/msg/?th=22605&start=0).